# Unexpected value returned by lastIndexOf() in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having an unexpected value returned by `lastIndexOf()`:

```
        //cache = "\nWELCOME TO THE LOTTERY GAME\n\n\n\t• Play\nRules\nSettings\n"
        //text = "\t• Play\nRules\nSettings\n"

        var start:int = cache.indexOf(text); //output: start == 31
        var end:int = cache.lastIndexOf(text); //output: end == 31 <- unexpected value
```

`end` is supposed to be `cache.length - 1` = `54`. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastIndexOf` does not return the end position of a match, rather it reruns the beginning index of a match searching from the end. Different value from `indexOf` is returned if there are multiple matches. For example:

```
s = "abcab"
```

Here `indexOf("ab")` will return 0 and `lastIndexOf("ab")` will return 3. But `lastIndexOf("ab")` won't return 4. If you want the end index of a match then you have to add the length of matched string.

```
var end:int = cache.lastIndexOf(text) + text.length;
```

Comment: I came up with this solution before but you've got the right answer so... And the best alternate is `var end:int = start + text.length;`

Answer (score 0):

May be you have expected the wrong result ;)

You should know that the only difference between [`String.indexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#indexOf%28%29) and [`String.lastIndexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#lastIndexOf%28%29) is the sens of searching, the first function is starting from the left ( from the char at position 0 ) and the second one is starting from the right ( from the char at position `string.length - 1` ) and both of them will return the position of the first char of your searched string compared to the calling string, if it exists of course.

**Example :**

```
var parent_string:String = 'hello world';
var parent_string_length:int = parent_string.length;

var child_string:String = 'world';
var child_string_length:int = child_string.length;

// h e l l o _ w o r l d
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

trace(parent_string.indexOf(child_string));     // gives : 6, it's the position of "w"
trace(parent_string.lastIndexOf(child_string)); // gives : 6, it's the position of "w"
```

To more understand, I will use two for loops to do what these functions do :

**`String.indexOf()` : find the first index of "child_string" in "parent_string" starting from the left :**

```
// h e l l o _ w o r l d
// ->          *
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

for(var i:int = 0; i < parent_string_length; i++)
{
    var char:String = parent_string.charAt(i);
    var substr:String = parent_string.substr(i, child_string_length);

    trace(i + ') ' + char + ' : ' + substr + ' == ' + child_string + ' : ' + (substr == child_string));

    if(char == child_string.charAt(0)){ // if we find the first char of "child_string" in "parent_string"

        if(substr == child_string){
            // 
            trace('the first index of "' + child_string +'" in "' + parent_string + '", starting from the left, is : ' + i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This for loop gives :

```
0) h : hello == world : false
1) e : ello  == world : false
2) l : llo w == world : false
3) l : lo wo == world : false
4) o : o wor == world : false
5)   :  worl == world : false
6) w : world == world : true
the first index of "world" in "hello world", starting from the left, is : 6
```

**`String.lastIndexOf()` : find the first index of "child_string" in "parent_string" starting from the right :**

```
// h e l l o _ w o r l d
//             *       <-
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

for(i = parent_string_length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    char = parent_string.charAt(i);
    substr = parent_string.substr(i, child_string_length);

    trace(i + ') ' + char + ' : ' + substr + ' == ' + child_string + ' : ' + (substr == child_string));

    if(char == child_string.charAt(0)){ // if we find the first char of "child_string" in "parent_string"
        if(substr == child_string){
            trace('the first index of "' + child_string +'" in "' + parent_string + '", starting from the right, is : ' + i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This for loop gives :

```
10) d : d == world : false
9) l : ld == world : false
8) r : rld == world : false
7) o : orld == world : false
6) w : world == world : true
the first index of "world" in "hello world", starting from the right, is : 6
```

Hope that things are more clear, and all that can help.